# how to review data from join table which have same field name in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have 3 tables as follows. I want to join them and review data in view. In my code there is an error called:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$firstname1
>
> Filename: views/boq_doc.php
>
> Line Number: 12

```
project table
id | staff_id | client_id | location

staff table
id | firstname | lastname | address

client table
client_id | firstname | lastname | address
```

I have written a model as follows to get table data from database:

```
function show_projects(){

$this->db->select("project.project_name, project.id, client.firstname AS firstname1, client.lastname AS lastname1,staff.firstname AS firstname2, staff.lastname AS lastname2, project.location,project.category, project.start_date, project.end_date"); 
$this->db->from('project');
$this->db->join('client', 'project.client_id = client.client_id');
$this->db->join('staff', 'staff.id = project.staff_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

And I want to view data and I have code as follows in view:

```
<?php foreach ($single_project as $project): ?>

<?php echo $project->location->location1; ?>

<?php  echo $project->firstname1; ?>

<?php  echo $project->lastname1; ?>

<?php  echo $project->firstname2; ?>

<?php  echo $project->lastname2; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**controller**

```
function show_project_id() {
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$data['projects'] = $this->project_list_model->show_projects();
$data['single_project'] = $this->project_list_model->show_project_id($id);
$this->load->view('boq_doc', $data);
}
```

Comment: `print_r($single_project)` in view and post its value!!

Comment: Please show your query. using $this->db->last_query();

Comment: function show_project_id() {
$id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$data['projects'] = $this->project_list_model->show_projects();
$data['single_project'] = $this->project_list_model->show_project_id($id);
$this->load->view('boq_doc', $data);
}

Comment: please add your controller code in your question

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 1 [client_id] => 1 [staff_id] => 1 [floor_plan_id] => 1 [category] => 0 [project_name] => testing 1 [location] => aaaaaaaaaaaaa [start_date] => [end_date] => ) )

Comment: See there is no firstname1 in your array

Comment: Change this `<?php foreach ($single_project as $project): ?>` to `<?php foreach ($projectsas $project): ?>` and check

Comment: yah.it only shows data in project table

Comment: you had the data in `$data['projects']` not in `$data['single_project ']`

Comment: thanx all. saty your code is work.thank u again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  controller code

`$data['projects'] = $this->project_list_model->show_projects();`

contain your query result form models

So in view you get it using

```
<?php foreach ($projects as $project): ?>
```